# Is there a Stack Exchange site that has a concentration of questions about ants?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a stack exchange site that includes or focuses on ants?

I have a few questions about ants that I might venture to ask, and I would like to see what other questions people have asked on the subject.

I searched on Area 51 but there doesn't seem to be anything there on the subject.

I'm referring to [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant), Ants are social insects of the family Formicidae.

Comment: [ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant "'Apache Ant (formerly Jakarta Ant) is a declarative, XML-based build tool for Java projects. ...'") - "9,818 questions tagged" as of now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you'd do best on Biology. They have the following tags:

- [entomology](/questions/tagged/entomology) [33 results](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=ant+%5Bentomology%5D)
- [zoology](/questions/tagged/zoology): [11 results](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=ant+%5Bzoology%5D)

Many of these questions focus directly on ants, e.g., "[Why do ants live so long?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/2785)" I bet your questions would fit right in. Since Biology is still in beta, [they could use your contributions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12502/biology). 
It's an old and [active beta](https://www.quantcast.com/biology.stackexchange.com?country=GLOBAL) too, so I think you could expect pretty good exposure for your questions.

You could consider Pets as well I suppose, but no [questions that mention ants there](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=ant) are really about ants to the same extent as the questions on Biology.

Comment: On Pets, the question would need to be in the context of caring for an ant farm or colony of some sort (I'm trying very hard _not_ to say 'domesticated ant' here, because that notion rather frightens me) .. but it would have to be about ants as pets.

Comment: @Tim: Yeah, I hoped anyone asking there would consider that an implication of the site title, but maybe that's too optimistic! I was thinking of ant farms when I checked for questions there, but having found none, I probably could've done just as well by not mentioning Pets at all. IDK, maybe it's a matter of the beta's age though – Biology is almost 4× older.

Comment: Ant farms / colonies would be a welcome topic there, I believe - which means general questions about helping ants thrive are probably a safe bet. If it's not in a 'pet' setting, biology is probably the best bet. Some strange overlap we have :)